Selecting the Source in the Field Map for a Spatial Join in a Model with an Iterator
I have create a model in ArcGIS Pro 3.3. I'm using iterate feature class to loop through a feature dataset. 3 of the features (polygons) in this dataset needs to move through a spatial join process and these features are denoted by SJ_XXX. To do this, I'm currently using an If Expresssion is. The code looks for SJ_ in the file name and returns True/False. I'm using Spatial Join process to transfer names from the polygons to my point feature class.
For these 3 features, I'm specifically looking to import a field called Area_Name and it's the same field name in all 3 features. However, because I'm using an iterator, when I open the field map section in the spatial join, I'm unable to navigate to the SJ feature classes. In the picture below, it's showing me the fields for the first feature class in the dataset. Ideally, my point feature class will a field like "SJ1_AreaName" and then listing the names, "SJ2_AreaName" and its values etc. Is there another method to map the relevant fields of the those 3 SJ features to the point feature? Below is a picture of my current model.



Can you create the field map in the spatial join tool using a different input?  Then delete that input and reconnect the iterated feature dataset input?  Model Builder is odd about what it 'remembers' and what it ignores sometimes.  I don't know if this will work, or if it will invalidate the model.  But I have used a similar technique in the past, but for a somewhat different situation.

@SonofaBeach thank you for your response. In the end, I couldn't figure it out. I ended up building the first part as a submodel (everything up until the spatial join part). I put that submodel in my main model and hard coded every spatial join into the model and making the SJ_ feature classes as parameters. Not quite as automated as I was hoping for, but I tried everything I could think of.
